# How can I get rid of these 3 PMS channels, without flattening it and losing the transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency

How can I get rid of these 3 PMS channels, without flattening it and losing the transparency?

Thanks All!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each spot channel you want to get rid of, you can:

- Ctl/Cmd-Click on the spot channel to load it as a selection
- Create a new layer and fill the selection with your chosen RGB color
- Delete the spot channel.

Be sure to keep the CMYK composite channel targeted except when deleting spot channels.

Transparency is unaffected, but you will have to be careful of your layer order to maintain the appearance of the composite.

Answer (score 2):

- Highlight a spot channel in the **Channel Panel**.
- Choose `Merge Spot Channel` from the **Channel Panel Menu**
- Repeat as needed :)

This **is going to flatten layers**. So if you want the transparency back, you should first create an alpha channel of the transparency. Then, after you merge the spot channels, you can load the alpha and apply a layer mask to reinstate the transparency.

Simply Command/Ctrl-Shift-Click the Channel thumbnails to load them as a selection (works the same was as Command/Ctrl-clicking to load a layers transparency as a selection), then create a new channel and remove your selection from it. You can then load that as a selection for a mask.

Basically, there's no easy way I know of to merge the spot channels and retain the transparency, so you need to plan ahead - 3 steps forward, 1 step back, to get to where you want to be essentially.